# Dataframe to Array for use in misc3d in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe that I would like to turn into a multidimensional array in R. This multidimensional array will be used in the `misc3d` package (`computeContour3d` function).

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)

x <- seq(0,5) 
y <- seq(1, 11, 2)
z <- seq(0, 5)

data <- expand.grid(x = x, y=y, z=z)
data <- cbind(data, value = rnorm(length(data$x), mean = 3))
```

**Attempt**

I found the `baseR` function `array`, which has a `data` attribute, a `dim` attribute, and a `dimnames` attribute but I am not sure how to use them.

The `data` attribute requires

> a vector (including a list or expression vector) giving data to fill
> the array.

I thought this should be the `data$value` column, then? How do you then input the `x,y,z` columns?

**Question**

How do you convert an dataframe into a multidimensional array in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought it would be something like this:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- seq(0,5) 
y <- seq(1, 11, 2)
z <- seq(0, 5)

data <- expand.grid(x = x, y=y, z=z)
data <- cbind(data, value = rnorm(length(data$x), mean = 3))

arr <- array(rnorm(nrow(data), mean=3), dim=c(length(x), length(y), length(z)))
computeContour3d(arr, x=x, y=y, z=z, level=.5)
```